# Java getters and setters

Tags: java

Below is the code I would like some help with.  I'm just trying to understand if there a better way to use getters and setters.  Can someone fill me in on the correct way to use them if there is a textfield, `JRadioButton` set that I am trying to get info from?

```
//This class sets gets all the information that the user has entered.
package edu.witc.TrainTicket.model;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import edu.witc.TrainTicket.view.*;

public class Destination {


    //Constructor with no arguments
    public Destination() {
    }


    public Destination(JRadioButton chicago, JRadioButton newYork, JRadioButton seattle, JRadioButton sanFransisco, JTextField name, JTextField phone) {

        String selectedDestination = getRadioButtonValue(chicago, newYork, seattle, sanFransisco);
        String custName = getCustName(name);
        String custPhone = getPhoneNum(phone);

        }


    public String getCustName(JTextField name){
        return name.getText();
    }

    public String getPhoneNum(JTextField phone){
        return phone.getText();
    }   

    //get the type of paint
    public String getRadioButtonValue(JRadioButton chicago, JRadioButton newYork, JRadioButton seattle, JRadioButton sanFransisco) {

        String selected = "";

        if(chicago.isSelected())
            selected = "Chicago";
        if(newYork.isSelected())
            selected = "New York";
        if(seattle.isSelected())
            selected=  "Seattle";
        if(sanFransisco.isSelected())
            selected=  "San Fransisco";

        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, selected);

        return selected;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note about useful comments: `//Constructor with no arguments` isn't one. `//Parameterless constructor required for xyz` is more informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your getters and setters would be for fields of the class, not passed in.  I'll use your two simplest ones as examples for you to work from.

```
public String getCustName(JTextField name){
    return name.getText();
}

public String getPhoneNum(JTextField phone){
    return phone.getText();
}
```

These methods make no sense if you think about them logically.  Your client code will pass in a `JTextField` that it already has, in order to invoke `getText()` on it?  Why wouldn't that code just do it itself?

Here's how getters and setters work:

```
private JTextField myTextField;

public String getMyTextFieldValue() {
    return myTextField.getText();
}

public void setMyTextField(JTextField newTextField) {
    myTextField = newTextField;
}
```

That's the general principle behind getters and setters.  You should be able to extend that logic to all of the other methods as well once you understand the logic.

Comment: Would I need a Constructor here

Comment: @JustinEsders Constructors are only needed if you either A) need/want default values in place or B) need to initialize other fields in your class. so in this simple case, he might need a constructor if myTextField is never initialized.